# Google Kubernetes Engine outage every 6 hours like clockwork?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have hit a strange issue in GKE on GCP where we have a few seconds to a minute if intermittent HTTP 500/520/525 errors trying to access our API every 6h10m give or take a couple minutes, and our logs haven't given us much to go on yet.

Our pipeline looks like:

```
user request -> CloudFlare -> GKE nginx LoadBalancer (ssl termination) -> GKE router pod -> API
```

Hitting CloudFlare or the GKE loadbalancer directly shows the same error, so seems like the issue is within our GCP setup somewhere.

In the past I've run into a [CloudSQL Proxy issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/87) where it renews an SSL cert every hour and caused very predictable, very brief outages.

Does GKE have a similar system we might be running into where it does something every 6h that is causing these errors for us?

Pingdom report:
[image: brief outage every 6h10m]

Comment: Can you please also show how you're measuring the downtime? Is it some service like `pingdom.com` or do you have a custom monitoring solution that queries a page? I'd be interested in reproing this. Can you please also deploy and monitor the sample app (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) and see if it reproduces?

Comment: Hey Ahmet, from a ticket with Google Support it looks like the problem was our NAT getting destroyed/recreated every 6h10m, and that was due to only 1 of 2 required healthcheck IPs being whitelisted. not sure how that caused the error to be so clockwork, but there it is. We added a firewall rule to allow the other IP and our NATs stopped cycling which in turn left the rest of the stack online.

Comment: Hello, I'm from Google, would it be possible for you to add this information as an answer to the question and for you to accept the answer? This will help others who come across this page (I realise you've already provided this information in a comment, but it would be very useful in an answer if you have the time, thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that only 1 of 2 [required healthcheck IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#health_check_source_ips_and_firewall_rules) for internal load balancing was whitelisted. not sure how that caused the error to be so clockwork, but updating our firewall rules has stopped the issue. Hope that helps someone in the future!